# Laravel 8 session token lost after redirect to external URL

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-8, session-cookies, laravel-middleware

I have a Laravel 8 website in which users fill in a form and click a link to take them to an external payment website.  Once the user has paid (or canceled payment), the payment website redirects the user to my site.  For about 30% of users, the browser cookie storing the laravel_session cookie is not included in the headers and the user is logged out of my website.  According to Apache logs, The browser/platform is not a consistent factor in whether the user's cookie disappears or not.

The payment site is calling my url with HTTPS.  HTTPS is forced on by Apache config, so I am sure that all users are starting off from the same domain they are being returned to.  Perhaps the only smidgen of doubt I have is that some users are using an old URL that redirects to the new URL using an .htaccess directive.  When I go to the old URL, I see the new URL in the browser's address bar, matching the redirect address in the payment site, so I do think that is all working normally.

When the user submits the form, it brings them to a controller method that does this:

```
public function saveForm(Request $request) {
<snip>
$temp = call_user_func([new $controllerClass, $function], $request);
$sessionCookie = Cookie::get(config('session.cookie'));
logger()->info('Session Cookie Value: ' . $sessionCookie); //always returns a proper value
return $temp;
}
```

Note that I am not calling a route here, and no route is defined for $function, so I don't expect any middleware to kick on the call to $function.

The $function in question makes a curl call to the payment website for a token. Upon success, I log the session value again for debugging, and redirect like this.  Note that I am not making any changes to the cookie before redirecting. :

```
$sessionCookie = Cookie::get(config('session.cookie'));
logger()->info('Session Cookie Value: ' . $sessionCookie); //always returns a proper value
return redirect()->away($url);
```

I am returning up the chain without using die or dd or anything that would kill execution.

I believe my middleware is pretty out-of-the-box:

```
  protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
   ];

   protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
   ];
```

My route for receiving the redirection from the payment site is under 'web':

```
Route::post('pay/accepted', [PayController::class, 'accepted'])->name('pay.accepted');
```

Session.php values:

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => true,
'encrypt' => false,
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'connection' => null,
 'table' => 'sessions',
'lottery' => [2, 100],
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => null,
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', null),
```

When the payment site redirects to mine, the first indication that something is wrong is that EncryptCookies::handle does not see a cookie in the headers.  Inside Authenticate::handle, Auth::check() is false and the user is redirected to auth/login.  Again, this only happens about 30% of the time, making it difficult to debug properly.

I'd be very grateful for any ideas on how to debug further.

Comment: Welcome. What is your `same_site` Setting at for the cookie? If it is set to `strict` then this is expected. Should be under your `config/session.php`

Comment: Thanks for your response.  There is no same_site setting in my config/session.php.  All occurrences of $config['same_site'] in Illuminate files seem to be $config['same_site'] ?? null, so I'm not sure if the effect is the same as "none". I will specifically set it to "none" in session.php to be sure.

Comment: By inspecting the cookies in my browser, I could see they were already set to "none", but I added 'same_site' => 'none' to config/session.php for clarity.  Thanks.

Comment: In config/session.php, I've now also set 'secure' = true, as it seems that as of Chrome 80, Chrome's default settings will not put the cookie in headers from a request originating from another site unless same_site = 'none' and 'secure' = true.  However, I never had this problem in testing.  This might explain why it was happening to ~ 30% of users.